# Why does the C++23 ranges adaptor require a callable object to be copy_­constructible?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

Some ranges adaptors such as [`filter_­view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.view), [`take_­while_­view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.take.while.view) and [`transform_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.transform.view) use `std::optional`'s cousin [*`copyable-box`*](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.copy.wrap) to store the callable object:

```
template<input_­range V, copy_­constructible F>
class transform_view : public view_interface<transform_view<V, F>> {
 private:
  V base_ = V();
  copyable-box<F> fun_;
};
```

which requires the callable `F` to be [`copy_­constructible`](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.copyconstructible#concept:copy_constructible), this also prevents us from passing in the callable that captures the move only object into `transform_view` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zefbj6sa9)):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <memory>

struct MoveOnlyFun {
  std::unique_ptr<int> x;
  MoveOnlyFun(int x) : x(std::make_unique<int>(x)) { } 
  int operator()(int y) const { return *x + y; }
};

int main() {
  auto r = std::views::iota(0, 5)
         | std::views::transform(MoveOnlyFun(1));
}
```

Since the [`view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/ranges#range.view) is not required to be `copy_constructible`, why do we require the callable to be `copy_constructible`? why don't we just use *`moveable-box`* to store callable instead of *`copyable-box`*? What are the considerations behind this?

### Update:

The recent proposal [P2494R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2494r0.html) also addresses this issue and proposes a detailed resolution.

Comment: Note: You are citing a draft standard of C++23 to talk about a C++20 issue. As the time between C++20's standardization and now passes, that draft will become more and more unlike C++20. In this case "copyable-box" is not [even a *thing* in C++20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/). It uses [`semiregular-box`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/range.semi.wrap).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the algorithms require copy-constructible function objects, and views are basically lazy algorithms.

Historically, when these adaptors were added, views were required to be `copyable`, so we required the function objects to be `copy_constructible` (we couldn't require `copyable` without ruling out captureful lambdas). The change to make `view` only require `movable` came later.

It is probably possible to relax the restriction, but it will need a paper and isn't really high priority.

Comment: "*All the algorithms require copy-constructible function objects.*" Any particular reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a documented rationale. Allowing algorithms to easily call other algorithms freely could be one (allowing move-constructible would require pass-by-reference if the caller still needs the function object afterwards, and the extra level of indirection isn't great if the function object has little or no state).

Comment: Maybe. But since `std::` algorithms can accept move-only functions, and if the standard does not explicitly prohibit this, perhaps we can relax the restrictions on `ranges::` algorithms.

Comment: "`std::` algorithms can accept move-only functions" - citation needed

Comment: Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ebrKaWxE6) allowed? Although it looks fine, I don't know if the standard prohibits this.

Comment: [It isn't](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms.requirements#10), but implementations can choose not to check, and if a particular algorithm's implementation happens to not copy then you can get away with it, so to speak.